# Pyramid, Chameleon and template rendering

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon, template-tal

I started a project with the Python web framwork 'Pyramid', using the template engine 'chameleon'.

I'm a beginner of this frameworks, but I have to use it for a customer.

I follow the steps in order to install the framework, then I started coding, just for training purpose!

My first application was a stupid, simple CRUD application.

What I'm doing is:

in my `__init__.py` I have, for each view, the following code:

config.add_view('myenglishdictionary.views.modify',route_name='modify_route',renderer='templates/base.pt')

base.pt is the main template with header and footer and a div with the following code:

```
<div>${body}</div>
```

in my file view.py each view has 2 lines like the following:

```
body = render('templates/list.pt',{'list':list ,'project':'myProject'}, request=request)
return {'body':body}
```

and in my list.pt there is the content which will be embedded in base.pt

All seemed to work good. But after an update of the libraries, now I can't see my template correctly.

Instead the actual html code there are html entities:

```
 &lt;div class="clear"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

so, obviously the page doesn't look well.

The problems seems to be in the render method, since the html of base.pt template is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `${}` syntax escapes the included text by default (to help defend against XSS injection attacks).

Instead, use the `structure:` prefix to tell the rendering engine to not escape your text:

```
<div>${structure: body}</div>
```